# What is the fundamental group of $RP^2\#T$, the real projective space of dimension 2 and T is a torus?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I would like to see how this is done, probably using van Kampen. How to see this space?

Comment: A connected sum can be split up as one space minus a hole, glued onto another space minus a hole, over a sphere. Apply van Kampen to this.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the open cover $\{U, V\}$ of $X = \Bbb{RP}^2 \# T$ where $U$ is a thickening of the punctured $\Bbb{RP}^2$ and $V$ is a thickening of the punctured torus inside $X$. $U \cap V$ deformation retracts to a circle.

Siefert-van Kampen theorem says

$$\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V)/\langle i_Ui_V^{-1} \rangle$$

where $i_U : \pi_1(U \cap V) \to \pi_1(U)$ is the map induced from the inclusion $U \cap V \hookrightarrow U$, and similar for $i_V$. As $\partial U = \partial V$ represents the class $a^2$ in $\pi_1(\Bbb{RP}^2 - D^2) \cong \pi_1(S^1) \cong \langle a \rangle$ and the class $bcb^{-1}c^{-1}$ in $\pi_1(T - D^2) \cong \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \cong \langle b, c\rangle$, $i_U$ sends $1$ to $a^2$ and $i_V$ sends $1$ to $bcb^{-1}c^{-1}$.

Thus, $\pi_1(X) \cong \langle a, b, c \rangle/\langle a^2[b, c]^{-1} \rangle \cong  \langle a, b, c | a^2 = [b, c] \rangle$.